# Laravel Auth - Not set the Auth::user yet

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I manage to update a secret_key column after the laravel login using Auth. However, what I want is to not set the Auth::user yet because I want to verify the user first by adding a verification that I send via email. The problem is that after I login the Auth::user already have a value and the other URLs are already accessible. Can anyone help me?

Cheers!

Comment: You need to run a middleware check along with perhaps a database field with an integer of `activated` defaulting to 0. If they click the link it'll update to 1. This way middleware can check the value and perform the correct actions.

Comment: How can I get the current user? I want to do this before the StartSession  middleware